# Help with recovering data on encrypted Microsd Card

Tags: data-recovery, adoptable-storage

Hi I was using a 64GB microsd card as internal storage on my Lenovo K4 Note (also known as Lenovo K4 Note A7010a48, A7010, Lenovo Vibe X3 Lite). Due to some issues in the display I had to give my cell phone to service center. While doing so unfortunately I did not take back up of the data. The service center guys factory reset my phone. Now I am unable to retrieve the data on the card and its showing as an empty card. I tried sending it to Stellar Data Recovery however they said it has unknown encryption and hence even though data is on the card it can not be recovered. CAN ANYONE HELP ME WITH A SOLUTION???

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you already checked with our [data-recovery](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info) and [adoptable-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) tag wikis? Hint: If your device is rooted, you can extract the encryption key and use that on a Linux machine to mount the storage. From there on, the usual recovery tools should be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If it was encrypted then you're not likely going to get anything back, as far as I'm aware.  I've had good success with Photorec on Linux to recover data from SD cards, so my first thought would be to spin up a Linux VM and give that a shot.

Comment: This is correct. If it was encrypted, all of that data is gone, no ifs ands or buts.